# In the flask-wtf, How to use value of form in the POST process?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

i'm new to flask-wtf and i'm encountering problem of Form for POST request.

I have a Form called `MyForm` which contains fields matched with keys of post parameters.

So, I have initialized Form with post parameter. in the view, it contains right values.

But, when the form is rendering with template, all the value of form is gone.

I can't access values of form in the template. in the way `form.field.data`.

However, all the value of `MyForm` can be handled in the template when i process GET method.

it makes me heart, and very annoying! why does value of form can't be handle by template in the POST process?

is that impossible to use value of form in template on POST method?

can anybody help me?

---

additional information : i pass the value of form to template function.

2nd additional information : OMG, i found that the form is not initialized in the POST process. but in the GET process, it works well.

does form of flask-wtf can not be initialized in POST process?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it myself.

Form is initialized with formdata parameter which contains json or request.form

usage is like this `MyForm(formdata=MultiDict(your json or request.form))`